# 8...8d5...5 is divisible by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I've been struggling with the following question: in a 99-digit multiple of 11, the first 49 digits are all 8s and the last 49 digits are all 5s. The question: what is the digit in the middle (50th position)?

I have no clue how to start with this question.

Comment: Do you know a simple criterion for divisibility by 11?( hint 10=-1 mod 11)

Comment: I removed the foundations tag. This is not a question regarding foundations of math.

Comment: @zoli hint +1 :  what is sum of all digits with alternating sign ?

Comment: Another strategy, one that is common in math, is to try to answer an easier question! Here, what would the middle digit need to be for the three digit number $8x5$? What about the five digit number $88x55$? Seven digit number $888x555$? etc.

Comment: @Alvinl: Oh, I see. The remainder is (8-8)+...+(8-8)+8-x+(5-5)+...+(5-5)+5 = 8-x+5 (mod 11), so x = 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number is divisible by $11$ if and only if the alternating sum of its digits is divisible by $11$. So effectively we only care about the middle part of the number:
$$ \underbrace{8\ldots 8}_{48}\,8X5\,\underbrace{5\ldots 5}_{48} $$
For which $X$ is the criterion (not) satisfied? ($8-X+5 \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$)